# RT8188eu driver problems (very old bug)

Tags: wifi, networking

After official kernel update, my rt8188eu chipset was not working on desktop machine. There was no wifi option in network settings.

So I downloaded the driver from GitHub and compiled myself, and it worked. But if I turn off wifi from the the panel of elementary OS (right side), I can't turn that back on from GUI, I need to execute "nmcli radio wifi on" each time. (This issue existed on stocked kernel that was packed with Elementary OS too, but in my laptop, no problem at all)

## My questions are -

1. " Do RT8188eu chipset drivers included in Linux Kernel ? I don't think so, I tried 4.10 with headers too. "
2. The graphical glitch in WiFi toggle button is an old but still unsolved issue. I have no idea which components are responsible for it. (I tried Arch Linux+GNOME and Linux Mint 18.1, and problem is not there.)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, try downloading UKUU (the Ubunutu Kernel Update Utility), and you can try to boot into some different kernels with minimum hassle. I successfully use 4.13.10. For 4.13 you would probably need [this kernel patch](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/issues/232), on top of driver.

Secondly, there might be other kernel modules that need to be enabled? ,

Finally, try filing an issue on the Github page: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/issues the fact you just need to run a command, as wifi radio is failing to switch correctly, sounds like something fixable.